# Flights delay make me unable to board subsequent train and flight tickets. Could I ask for refund

Tags: air-travel, refunds

A Singaporean airline arrived one hour later than announced to its final destination (within EU). Therefore I was unable to board my train, which led to another airport for my next flight (destination inside EU). I had complained with the steward and they seemed to log it into their system.

I had to spend a night at the airport and bought another ticket.

If I ask for a refund of the new ticket, are there any laws that I can build my claims on?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173056/missed-connection-long-delay-on-an-iberia-american-flight-from-us-to-spain-am If you booked separate tickets, AFAIK Singapore airlines has no responsibility for you missing your train and subsequent flight. You should try to claim on your travel insurance.

Comment: @Traveller, The related question is about a single booking, and thus the airline did get OP to the destination. Here it looks like separate tickets (unless a plane-train-plain ticket is sold as one?).

Comment: Some EU airlines (eg, Lufthansa) do sell train segments as "flights" so it is possible that this was on a single ticket.  Maybe not likely (if only because in that case there should have been no need to purchase another ticket), but certainly possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I ask for a refund of the new ticket, are there any laws that I can build my claims on?

Assuming this was booked on separate tickets this is a clear "no". Article 15 of Singapore Airline's contract of carriage clearly states:

> ... If a Passenger holds more than one ticket and where such separate ticket(s) is not a conjunction ticket issued in connection with the Carrier’s ticket, Carrier shall have no obligations, duties or liabilities, whether to the Passenger or otherwise, in respect of such separate ticket(s) not issued by Carrier.

https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/global_footer/conditions-carriage/

Comment: This is the simple and obvious correct answer.